# Laravel 5.1 Pass middleware parameters as array

Tags: laravel-5.1

i have a route group in which i will check the rank of the user by middleware:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'expert'], function () {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'partner', 'middleware' => 'rank:4,5'], function () {
        Route::get('/search', 'PartnerController@getSearch');
        Route::post('/result', 'PartnerController@postSearch');
    });
});
```

the middleware is registred in the kernel.php :

```
 protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'rank' => \App\Http\Middleware\checkRank::class,
];
```

here is my class :

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;

class checkRank {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $ranks) {

        //return $next($request);
        return print_r($ranks);

    }
}
```

all i wanna see is the array with the values [4,5]

but all i get is 4

PHP-Version is 5.6.11

trying this way according to : http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware#middleware-parameters

Comment: That's strange, here is the same code and it works. https://ahesanalisuthar.wordpress.com/2015/06/04/laravel-5-1-pass-middleware-parameters-as-array/

Comment: yes i know this artikel :-(
i also get this error:

UnexpectedValueException in Response.php line 403: The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.

Comment: have you tried it without a group just to check if that works?

Comment: yes i did but wont work

Answer (score 10):

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$ranks) {}
```

i forgot the three dots in front of $ranks

Comment: after some research it makes sense now. It's a new feature of php 5.6. In your case it means for the handle function: first varibale is the request, then the next variable and the rest will be stored are an array in $ranks ;) http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2014/php-5-6-and-the-splat-operator